# Pasting image to chart through coding gets blurred

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem when pasting an image on a chart.

This is a cut sample of my code

```
ws.Paste
Set MyChart = wb.Charts.Add
MyChart.Name = "ImageChart"
Set MyChart = MyChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name)
MyChart.ChartArea.Width = ws.Shapes(1).Width
MyChart.ChartArea.Height = ws.Shapes(1).Height
MyChart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0 
ws.Shapes(1).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
MyChart.ChartArea.Select
MyChart.Paste
```

I am adjusting the height and width of the chart to be the same as the image and when it paste, it gets blurred. But when I am doing it manually, the quality of the image stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the picture as a high-resolution metafile...

Change the first argument to `CopyPicture` to `xlPrinter`.

Comment: I will change the` xlScreen` to `xlPrinter`? I tried and it still saving a blurred image. did on the `xlPicture` and still the same. I also tick the "Don not crompress image file" in the advanced settings. – remoel 9 mins ago

Comment: Guess the xlPrinter will do. Thanks Sir :)